# Using decltype to initialise container

Tags: c++

When I dereference an iterator of a container (e.g. `*v.begin()`), I always get a reference to the contained type. And then, I cannot use `decltype` to initialize another container.

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> a;
  vector<decltype(*a.begin())> b;
  return 0;
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Use `std::remove_reference`. Look it up.

Comment: `std::vector<decltype(a)::value_type> b;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Choice 1:**

The simplest way to declare `b` is to use `decltype(a)` as the container type.

```
decltype(a) b;
```

**Choice 2:**

The next level of indirectness to declare `b` is to use `decltype(a)::value_type` as the contained type.

```
std::vector<decltype(a)::value_type> b;
```

**Choice 3:**

The most round-about way to declare `b` is to use `std::remove_reference` to remove the reference from the dereferenced iterator.

```
std::vector<std::remove_reference<decltype(*a.begin())>::type> b;
```